# NLP as a Poisson Regression Problem?

Tags: natural-language, poisson-regression

Suppose I encode the sequence to sequence dataset as a vector of integer $\{0,1\cdots N\}$ where $N$ is the maximun number of unique words in the dataset.

For example, I am planning to build a chatbot with inputs maximum of 8 words:

> Q:Where can I buy these apples ?
> $$
> [8,19,23,5,76,10,2,0]
> $$
> A:At the market downtown $$
> [44,7,12,90,0,0,0,0]
> $$

Can I use multivariate Poisson Regression to fit the data such that when I inputted an unseen sentence

> New Input: Where to buy apples ?
> $$
> [8,65,32,10,2,0,0,0]
> $$
> Output: At the market downtown $$
> [44,7,12,90,0,0,0,0]
> $$

Is there any violations in the conditions for using the MVP regression?

Comment: The words have no inherent ordering (maybe alphabetical, but you don’t even seem to be using that), so I am skeptical that this makes sense. For instance, why is it that $market=12$ and $downtown=90?$

Comment: @Dave I am using the predictors as an identification token through an integer which could be arbitrary (no ordering) but is consistent.